# Finding friends who also use the same iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

So basically what I'm trying to find out what would be the easier/best way to allow a user to see who in their contacts uses the same app, like snapchats feature, I haven't done too much looking into it but I'm sure someone could shine some light and point me in the right direction 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking:

This would be accomplished by having a web server where you would store your users information, including their phone number. You would then ask a users permission to use their address book, upload the address book to your server, and see what contacts in the users address book have user accounts on your server. Then return the contacts that have accounts on your server to the user.

Comment: That was my first initial thoughts about doing it, but i wasn't sure if there was an easier way.

Comment: you need to handle the scenario where the User denies access to Contacts. You can't upload data that you don't have access to.